# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast - rand()

Tags: c, pointers, integer

Ok here is my problem. I am using srand for the first time and I am getting "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning. I have read through many threads on here and I still don't see what is wrong. I will post the relevant parts since the problem is long.

declaration of the fucntion

```
void getFinalsRandom(int*, int*, int*);
```

function called in Main()

```
int finalsDayRandom;
int finalsTimeRandom;
int finalsTimeRandomSat;

getFinalsRandom(&finalsDayRandom, &finalsTimeRandom, &finalsTimeRandomSat);
```

actual code inside function

```
void getFinalsRandom(int *finalDay, int *finalTime, int *finalTimeSat)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  finalDay = rand() % 6;
  finalTime = rand() % 5;
  finalTimeSat = rand() % 4;
}
```

I also include time.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h, math.h

Answer (score 4):

Don't call srand in your function, call it once per run of the program.

then change your function like this:

```
void getFinalsRandom(int *finalDay, int *finalTime, int *finalTimeSat)
{
   *finalDay = rand() % 6;
   *finalTime = rand() % 5;
   *finalTimeSat = rand() % 4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace

```
finalDay = rand() % 6;
finalTime = rand() % 5;
finalTimeSat = rand() % 4;
```

with

```
*finalDay = rand() % 6;
*finalTime = rand() % 5;
*finalTimeSat = rand() % 4;
```

As is currently, you are actually overwriting the local copy of the *pointer* with the random number, not the *value at the pointer*.

Comment: wow, I was sure I tried that when I was trouble shooting. I think maybe I tried & instead. Thanks a bunch solved it instantly.

Comment: @CraigPlazony No problem. Please accept one of the answers if they solved the problem (big checkbox next to the answer) so that people know you've got it.